# Meaning of C construct

Tags: c

In the code below, what is the role of the `int sid=*(int*)args` construct?

```
void *thread_p(void *args)
{
    int sid=*(int*)args,i,size=0;***This initialisation in the thread function means what?***
    char msg[100];

    while(1)
    {
            for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                msg[i]='\0';

            recv(sid,msg,100,0);
            printf("\nClient:%s",msg);
            printf("\nServer:");
            gets(msg);

            size=strlen(msg);
            send(sid,msg,size,0);
            if((strcmp(msg,"exit"))==0)
            {  
                close(sid);
                exit(1);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with multithreading but everything with the actual programming language that you are using. Which is that exactly? That said, assuming C, the right-hand side is evaluated as `*((int*)args)`, i.e. first cast to `int*` then dereference.

Comment: Or in other words, sid is assigned the value of the int that args points to. It is assumed that args points to an address where a meaningful int is stored.

Comment: It means that you are reading `sizeof(int)` bytes from the address pointed to by `args`, and writing those bytes into the local variable `sid`. If the address pointed to by `args` is not aligned to `int` (i.e., not divisible by `sizeof(int)`) **AND** your platform (compiler + HW) does not support unaligned load/store operations, then it will yield a runtime error (either an **immediate** memory access violation, or even worse - you'll get some "junk" data in variable `sid` and your program will behave unexpectedly **at some random point** later in the execution).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here that thread_p is a pthread_create start routine. Such a start routine is required to accept a void pointer, which in C and C++ means a pointer to an untyped block of memory. Now, in addition to a start routine, pthread_create also accepts a void pointer argument, which it passes to the start routine. It is up to the caller of pthread_create to coordinate the call to pthread_create with the code in the start routine. So if the start routine given to pthread_create assumes the void pointer points to, say, an integer, then the call to pthread_create must pass a pointer to an integer as the arg parameter to keep things in sync. This is a type-unsafe interface. The compiler won't help you make sure these are in sync, and if they are not, you'll get undefined behavior.

Your thread_p function is assuming that the arg passed to it actually points to an integer. It is first casting the void pointer to an integer pointer (that is the (int*)args part) and then dereferencing the pointer to get the integer that it points to (that's the * in front of the (int*)args). If the caller of pthread_create passed it thread_p, but failed to pass the address of an int as the arg parameter, the code would have undefined behavior.